# Cursive Words not connecting in image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, python-itertools, python-unicode

[OutPut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0egNn.png) /  [Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Az1f.png)

I am generating images for cursive scripts through font and its unicode but in output image characters are separate not joined. i need joined characters same as expected image.
Please ask if question is not clear.
Images are linked above.

```
unicode_text = u"\u0627\u0628\u062A\u062B"
list_of_letters = list (unicode_text)
folder = 1
n=3
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for word in itertools.permutations( list_of_letters,i):
   char = ''.join(word)
   verdana_font = ImageFont.truetype("Nafees Naskh v2.01.ttf", 30, encoding="unic")
   text_width, text_height = verdana_font.getsize(''.join(word))
   canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255),)
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
   canvas.save(path + '\\' + char[::-1]+'.png', "PNG")
   folder += 1
```

Comment: What line is responsible for adding the text to the image?

Comment: draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
       draw.text((5,5), char, font = verdana_font, fill = "#000000")

Comment: It is not in your example code. You should add it.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say you should specify features. See http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text

```
PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text(xy, text, fill=None, font=None, anchor=None,
    spacing=0, align="left", direction=None, features=None)
```

`features` should be a list with the feature(s) responsible of chaining this chars. I do not know enough about arbic script. But it is likely some ligature, positioning and/or substitution feature.

For a list of features see:
https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/featurelist.htm

The docs also mention that this requires `libraqm` to be installed.